# Inconsistent output order of std::cout and std::cerr in CLion

Tags: c++, std, c++20, iostream

I'm experiencing an inconsistent behavior with the output order of `std::cout` and `std::cerr` in the console of CLion

I have a simple C++ program that includes both `std::cout` and `std::cerr` statements. Ideally, I expect the outputs to appear in the order they are encountered in the code. However, I am noticing that sometimes the output from `std::cout` appears first, while other times the output from `std::cerr` is displayed first.

Here's a minimal reproducible example that demonstrates this issue:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "This is a cout statement." << std::endl;
    std::cerr << "This is a cerr statement." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code multiple times without any modifications, the order of the outputs varies, which is quite confusing during my development process as I rely on the consistent ordering for debugging purposes.

I am currently using CLion version 2023.3.2 on MacOS14.2. I have checked for any relevant updates or settings related to the console output, but couldn't find anything that resolves this issue.

Could someone please shed some light on this matter? Are there any known issues or workarounds for this inconsistent behavior?

Thank you in advance for your help!

The expected output in the console should be consistent and reflect the order of the statements in the code:

```
This is a cout statement.
This is a cerr statement.
```

Comment: looks like this is a known issue for CLion.  Looking to see if there is a workaround.

Comment: The top link should now point you to a potential workaround.